# Why is my radio button in XAML using MAUI not clickable on android?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I've got a page that requires the user to choose between two options- I'm using a radio button for it, but for the formatting I needed to make a custom ControlTemplate so the button can look like all our others. The custom template I'm using is as follows:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameRadioTemplate">
            <Frame Padding="0" BorderColor="#006A97" CornerRadius="1"       
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="Start">

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#008000"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffffff"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid WidthRequest="70">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

And when viewing this in Visual Studio's Windows Machine, it works fine- I can click on my radio buttons, they select, everything works fine. But when I tried it on Android, suddenly the radio buttons are unclickable- they display & show up how I want, but nothing happens when I tap on them.

I've tried googling for similar situations, but can't seem to find any other examples of a button's functionality stopping when going over to Android. Unsure how to tackle this

Comment: I have been having similar behavior and it was due to the stacking of controls that were intercepting the mouse gestures. Whilst it wasn't obvious I had to set `IsEnabled="False"` on controls that I suspected were stealing the mouse input, after which, my app started working. Perhaps the same approach will work for you.

Comment: Hello, you could try using Border instead of Frame. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's the issue with Frame.

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead,

I just changes Frame to Border, and it worked well on my side,

```
<Border Padding="0" Stroke="#006A97"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
   HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="Start">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="1"/>
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        ...

    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid WidthRequest="70">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Hope it helps!